# Difference between a regular language and a regular grammar

Tags: grammar, regular-language

My book gives similar but slightly different explanations of regular grammar and regular language.
I doubt it's wrong, is a regular language the same thing of a regular grammar?
The definition of my book is:
A grammar is regular if all the productions are V-> aW or V->Wa with V,W non terminal or terminal symbols, "a" terminal symbol.W can also be empty or be the same of V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A formal grammar is a set of rules, whereas a formal language is a set of strings.

A regular grammar is a formal grammar that **describes** a regular language.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar):

> [T]he left regular grammars generate exactly all regular languages. The right regular grammars describe the reverses of all such languages, that is, exactly the regular languages as well.
>
> If mixing of left-regular and right-regular rules is allowed, we still have a linear grammar, but not necessarily a regular one.

In the above, left-regular rules are rules of the form `V->Wa` (right-regular, of the form `V->aW`).

Answer (score 4):

Regular grammars and regular languages are two different terms:

1. A *language* is a (possibly infinite) set of valid sequences of terminal symbols.
2. A *grammar* defines which are the valid sequences.

The same language could be represented with different class of grammars (regular, context free, etc.). **A *language* is said to be regular if it can be represented with a regular *grammar***. On the othet hand, a regular grammar always defines a regular language. What you have posted is the definition of the regular grammar.

See [this Wikipedia post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

I think if I explain the difference between a `language` and `grammar`, your queries will automatically get resolved.

A `language` is a set of strings over some set of alphabets satisfying certain rules encoded as grammars, while
`Grammars` are used to generate languages.

So basically `grammars` denote the syntactical rules of a string and the set of strings that can be generated with the start symbol of the grammar is called the `Language` of the `grammar`